# understanding the controller scope in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

Consider two div areas as follows, in html file

```
<div class="divArea1" ng-controller="myController">
   <input ng-click="updateName()" type="button" value="button"/>
</div>

<div class="divArea1" ng-controller="myController">
  <p>{{name}}</p>
</div>
```

Following is the angular js example

```
productApp.controller("myController", [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.name= "XYZ";
    $scope.updateName= function() {
        $scope.name = "ABC";
    };
} ]);
```

problem is when I am trying to update the name, upon click on update button it is not visible in the second in the div area. Is there any mistake i am doing.

Comment: you have **two** controller, so they have own scopes. When you do `ng-controller="myController"` angular behind do something like `new myController(...dependencies...)` so you just create two instances

Comment: You should put your controller in the parent container of those two divs. Even if you name the controller the same way, angular instanciates it twice, with two different scopes

Comment: if you use it inside one div it should work , as angular $scope inherits from the parent controller

Comment: ya it works when wrap them within the one div, Thank you all for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controllers are not singletons. Each time you have a new controller, you're having a new instance of this controller, with a new isolated scope.

If your need is to share data between controllers, you should use a factory (which is a singleton).

```
angular.module('app').factory('mySharedData', function(){
   var service = {
       object : objectToShare
   };

   var objectToShare =  {};

   return service;
});
```

And from your controller :

```
angular.module('app').controller('myController', 
    ['$scope','mySharedData', 
    function($scope, mySharedData){
        $scope.someObject = mySharedData.object;
        $scope.updateName= function() {
            $scope.someObject.name = "ABC";
        };
    }
]);
```

And from your view :

```
<div class="divArea1" ng-controller="myController">
   <input ng-click="updateName()" type="button" value="button"/>
</div>

<div class="divArea1" ng-controller="myController">
  <p>{{someObject.name}}</p>
</div>
```

Note : I've encapsulated the name property into an object because objects are passed by reference, and strings by value. This allows you to make it easier to share your values and to have it automatically updated into the service and other controllers, without having to access your property through accessors.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is two different controllers (with two separate scopes) with the same name.

You need to put the controller in the parent controller to keep the name in the same scope as the button:

```
<div id="container" ng-controller="myController">
   <div class="divArea1">
      <input ng-click="updateName()" type="button" value="button"/>
   </div>

   <div class="divArea1">
     <p>{{name}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is demo http://jsfiddle.net/wg7pb1yu/3/
inject $rootScope so that it will do from global scope

```
productApp.controller("myController", [ '$scope','$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
$rootScope.name= "XYZ";
$scope.updateName= function() {
    $rootScope.name = "ABC";

};} ]);
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: The use of rootScope is not recommended, since it overloads the digest()

Comment: instead injection `$rootScope` you can use [`$scope.$root`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$root)